# No error messages from validate?

Tags: forms

I'm creating a simple contact form and it works flawlessly, besides the validation.

When I try to exercise the validate function, no error messages are shown. The text in the correspondent field turns red, so that works, but where is the messages?

If I fill in the form correctly and the mail gets sent, messages are shown just like they should.

Here's my code:

```
function mymodule_buysell_contact_form($form, &$form_state) {
    // The form

    $form['contact'] = array(

        '#title' => t('Skicka ett meddelande till säljaren'),

        '#type' => 'fieldset'

    );
    $form['contact']['message'] = array(

        '#type' => 'textarea',

        '#title' => t('Meddelande:'),

        '#cols' => 35,

        '#rows' => 6,

        '#resizable' => FALSE

    );
    $form['contact']['name'] = array(

        '#type' => 'textfield',

        '#title' => t('Ditt Namn:'),

        '#size' => 35,

        '#maxlength' => 30

    );
    $form['contact']['compname'] = array(

        '#type' => 'textfield',

        '#title' => t('Företag:'),

        '#size' => 35,

        '#maxlength' => 30

    );
    $form['contact']['phone'] = array(

        '#type' => 'textfield',

        '#title' => t('Telefon:'),

        '#size' => 35,

        '#maxlength' => 30

    );
    $form['contact']['cellphone'] = array(

        '#type' => 'textfield',

        '#title' => t('Mobiltelefon:'),

        '#size' => 35,

        '#maxlength' => 30

    );

    $form['contact']['mail'] = array(

        '#type' => 'textfield',

        '#title' => t('Din E-mail:'),

        '#size' => 35,

        '#maxlength' => 30

    );

    $form['contact']['captcha'] = array (
        '#type' => 'captcha',
        '#captcha_type' => 'image_captcha/Image',
    );

    $form['contact']['submit'] = array(

        '#type' => 'submit',

        '#value' => t('Skicka')

    );

    return $form;
    }

    function mymodule_buysell_contact_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    // Validate message

    $valid_message = $form_state['values']['message'];

        if (empty($valid_message)) {

        form_set_error('message', 'Du har inte skrivit något meddelande');

        }
    // Validate if a name is submitted

    $valid_name = $form_state['values']['name'];

        if (empty($valid_name)) {

        form_set_error('name', 'Du har inte fyllt i ett namn');

        }

    // Validate if a company name is submitted

    $valid_compname = $form_state['values']['compname'];

        if (empty($valid_compname)) {

        form_set_error('compname', 'Du har inte fyllt i ditt företagsnamn');

        }
    // Validate phone by look for numbers

    $valid_phone = $form_state['values']['phone'];

        if (!is_numeric($valid_phone)) {

        form_set_error('phone', 'Ditt nummer verkar inte vara korrekt ifyllt (endast siffror)');

        }
    // Validate cellphone by look for numbers

    $valid_cellphone = $form_state['values']['cellphone'];

        if (!is_numeric($valid_cellphone)) {

        form_set_error('cellphone', 'Ditt mobilnummer verkar inte vara korrekt ifyllt (endast siffror)');

        }

    // Validate the mail, using Drupals own function

    $valid_email = $form_state['values']['mail'];

        if (!valid_email_address($valid_email)) {

        form_set_error('mail', 'Din Epost verkar inte vara korrekt ifylld');

        }
}
```

Comment: Did you try disabling the CAPTCHA module, and removing the CAPTCHA field in the form?

Comment: It is not necessary to use a validation handler just to verify if a form field is empty; it's enough you use the property "#required" and set it to `TRUE`.

Comment: I did try to remove the CPATCHA, but it didnt work..
And thank you for the tip, I'll try that.

Comment: By the way, `t()` is only used for translating from English to the language set for the Drupal site; the string passed to `t()` needs then to be in English. If you want to only to show the user interface's strings in a specific language, then you should not call `t()`.

Comment: Thank you. I have removed that now. The #required = TRUE isnt showing any error either...

Comment: Daniel did you ever manage to work this out? I have the same problem, none of the form_set_error() messages come across.

Comment: Sorry, Ain. I think that I just let this one go.

Answer (score 1):

For fieldsets I think you have to include the parent as well.

Try changing

form_set_error('**phone**', 'Ditt nummer v.... 
to

form_set_error('**contact][phone**', 'Ditt nummer v....

You can read more here: http://drupal.org/node/678816

Comment: Sorry, that did not help. Using D7, btw and this exact thing works on another form in the very same module.

Comment: As far as I can see, Drupal 7 uses the name of the field only, too; the syntax you are referring is used when the property `#parents" is set for the form field for which you are reporting the error.

Comment: Right? But it just wont work..